# how to make a word turn into certain commands in vim command line?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, key-bindings, neovim

I want `:cup` in vim command line to turn into `:tabdo call MapRunCmd()<CR>`

Hope that somebody can help me out

PS: I've tried this `nnoremap :cup :tabdo call MapRunCmd()<CR>` but didn't like this mapping. 
'cause i have to blindly type at a stretch

Comment: Have a look at :command (Christina makes some points about simplifying your answer) or :cnoreabbrev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close with trying a map command, but you want to define a command line mode mapping, not a normal mode mapping.

```
cnoremap cup tabdo call MapRunCmd()<CR>
```

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt christian's [solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/34427/how-to-make-a-word-turn-into-certain-commands-in-vim-command-line/34429#comment62023_34428) works too.. may come in handy

Comment: if i have more than two commands in a single mapping (separated by |), i would prefer christian's code.. also downside of `cnoremap` if i don't type the word at a stretch or pause a little bit, vim will **trigger wrong** for example- almost same words like cup, hackercup .. `:hacker[pause]cup`

Answer (score 1):

@ChristianBrabandt 's simple solution

type `:Cup` in vim command line, it will turn into `:tabdo call MapRunCmd()`

```
:com -nargs=0 Cup tabdo call MapRunCmd()
```

Comment: why the `printf` and the `TermWrapper` function? Doesn't that already do: `:com -nargs=0 Cup :tabdo :call MapRunCmd()`?

Comment: thank you very much :)  .. updated my solution